# how to insert array values into specific td id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, ajax

```html
<table id="tbl" class="tbl1">
  <tr>
    <th>
      mobileno
    </th>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

I am able to get specific values by using for loop but I am not able append those specific values into specific td id.I already set a id of td into html table.but I am able to append only in 1st row and then for second row it is not inserting those further specific values into that next row.
how to insert array values into specific td id

Comment: you tried $("#mo_"+i) instead of $("#mo_1")??

Comment: what is the folio() used for where it is defined?

Comment: Are you particularly attached to the way you have written your javascript? I can think of a few easier ways to go about this, providing more dynamic functionality in the process.

Comment: var mo_id = $("#tbl td").attr('id');

Comment: the way wrote above I want to get id of td

Comment: Okay, do you want the values inside - like <td id="mo_1"> 111 </td> etc?

Comment: var mo_id = $("#tbl td").attr('id');$("#mo_"+i).append(intmo[j]); i want in this way that those arrray  values will goto <td id="mo_1">111</td>

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your array:

```
  var intArr = [111, 201, 345, 434, 532, 677, 790, 890, 989, 118, 107, 136, 125, 153, 142];
```

And

```
$("#mo_" + i).append(arrfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$("#mo_" + i).append(intmo[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  This

```js
var arrfo = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  var intArr = [111, 201, 345, 434, 532, 677, 790, 890, 989, 118, 107, 136, 125, 153, 142 ];
  populatevalues(intArr);
});


function populatevalues(intArr) {
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (j = i * 3; j < 3; j++) {
      var arrfo = intArr[j];
      $("#mo_"+j).append(arrfo);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl" class="tbl1">
  <tr>
    <th>
      mobileno
    </th>
    <td id="mo_0"> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      mobileno
    </th>
    <td id="mo_1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      mobileno
    </th>
    <td id="mo_2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      mobileno
    </th>
    <td id="mo_3">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      mobileno
    </th>
    <td id="mo_4">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      mobileno
    </th>
    <td id="mo_5">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: in this way its not working where used #mo+j.this only inserting for 1st row  and my html page is the way i hvg code.dont make 1st cell as mo_0

Comment: var mo_id = $("#tbl td").attr('id');$("#mo_"+i).append(a); i want in this way

Comment: according to your looping only i can be 0.

Comment: I solved my issue by using only for loop only. thanks everyone for suggesting all of your own idea

Answer (score 0):

Update: This is now nothing like your code, however it will allow you to dynamically insert items from strm array into `<td></td>` BUT the td MUST have class mo - like so `<td class="mo" id="mo_1"></td>` You may keep the id's you have. They do not interfere with the code.

An explanation: I use the jQuery.each() "`$.each(function(){})`" function to irerate through each html element which has 'class="mo"', inserting the corresponding strm array item as the function progresses, until there are no more mo's in the object list. This will allow you to add as many elements with class mo and strm items as you like, without having to change any jquery code.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() { // encapsulate all functions in document ready function

    // this is the strm array, in order to have a proper array you must have values inside "value" separated by ,
    var strm = ["111", "201", "345", "434", "532", "677", "790", "890", "989", "118", "107", "136", "125", "153", "142"];
    // execute mo, pass strm array to function.
    mo(strm);

    // mo function with array as input value
    function mo(array) {
      // jQuery.each() method.
      // pass array as input value.
      $.each(array, function(i, val) { // << index and value of each item in strm array
        // if i is less than or equal to the number of elements with class mo,
        if (i <= $(".mo").length) {
          // get element with class mo equal to strm array index, insert value
          $(".mo").get(i).append(val);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl" class="tbl1">
  <tr>
    <th>
      mobileno
    </th>
    <td class='mo' id="mo_0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      mobileno
    </th>
    <td class='mo' id="mo_1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      mobileno
    </th>
    <td class='mo' id="mo_2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      mobileno
    </th>
    <td class='mo' id="mo_3">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      mobileno
    </th>
    <td class='mo' id="mo_4">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      mobileno
    </th>
    <td class='mo' id="mo_5">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: actually If my static array having more than 15 values so I want to append those more than 15 values into dynamic row of same html table.that's why I am using for loop here forthe purpose of inserting array values which having less than or equal to 15 values into html table .where each row can have minimum 1 value and maximum 3 values into each row of html table

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer to provide a perfectly good dynamic insert function using jQuery. I hope it fits your needs, and you learn something from it! :)